# class extending GCanvas won't do as told by addComponentListener

Tags: java

After importing java.awt.event.*, I've added a component listener to a class extending GCanvas with the following code:

```
public NameSurferGraph() {
addComponentListener(this);
nameList = new ArrayList<NameSurferEntry>();
}

public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) { }
public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) { }
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) { update(); }
public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) { }

public void update() {
removeAll();
drawBackground();
if (nameList.size()>0) {
for (int i=0; i<nameList.size(); i++) {;
drawLineForOneName(i);
}
}
}
```

But when I call a method on it from another class, nothing happens.

```
public NameSurferGraph graph = new NameSurferGraph();

public void graphName(String name) {
entry = database.findEntry(name);
graph.addEntry(entry);
graph.update();
}
```

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't provide enough code, I can only guess:

Your call to `removeAll();` removes all elements from `nameList`, so the `if` stops you from entering the loop (even if it did not, the loop body will be executing 0 times as the size of an empty collection is 0)

Comment: Whoops--sorry about not giving enough code.  Is the proper form with something like this on SO to update the question or post a new question?

Comment: (I just joined yesterday, so I'm still feeling my way around.)

Comment: Yes, you can update your question -- click on the "edit" link under the tags